# How to dynamically add an array to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am trying to dynamically add an array to an object. That is, starting with

```
 {colour: "white", type: "electric"};
```

and ending with

```
{colour: "white", type: "electric", owners: ["person1", "person2", "person3"] };
```

Consider the following object below

```
let car = {colour: "white", type: "electric"};
```

If I want to add another property to this object, I can check if it exist. Then add to it as follows.

```
if( typeof car.status === "undefined")
    car.status = "sold";
```

**What i have tried**

Using the above logic I tried the following

```js
let car = {
  colour: "white",
  type: "electric"
};

if (typeof car.owners === "undefined")
  car.owners.push("person1");
```

but this doesn't work.

**The question**

How do I add an array to an object?

Comment: By adding it: `car.owners = []` (instead of using a non-existing one)

Comment: follow this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693812/how-to-dynamically-add-an-array-to-an-object/59694475#59694475
you can get your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an array to an object, you create the array and assign it to a property:

```js
let car = {
  colour: "white",
  type: "electric"
};

if (typeof car.owners === "undefined") {
  //           vvvvvvvvvvv----- creates the array
  car.owners = ["person1"];
  // ^^^^^^^^^--- assigns it to the property
}

console.log(car);
```

If you want to *add to* that array later, you can use `push`. But the array has to exist first. E.g., something like:

```
// `person` has the person to add...
if (typeof car.owners === "undefined") {
  car.owners = [person];
} else {
  car.owners.push(person);
}
```

That said, it's best to avoid changing the shape of objects unnecessarily. I'd just start with an empty array and do away with the `if`:

```js
let car = {
  colour: "white",
  type: "electric",
  owners: [] // <=== Empty array
};

car.owners.push("person1");

console.log(car);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the status property exists in the object then u have to follow the below way

```
let car = {colour: "white", type: "electric",status:"somethings!"};
if(car.status){
  car.status = "sold";
}
console.log(car)
// o/p { colour: 'white', type: 'electric', status: 'sold' }
```

If the status property does not exist in the object

```
let car = {colour: "white", type: "electric"};
if(car.status){
  car.status = "sold";
}
console.log(car)
// o/p { colour: 'white', type: 'electric' }
```

If the Array property exists inside the object then you should follow the below sample code

```
let car = {colour: "white", type: "electric"};
if(car.owners && car.owners.length > 0){
  // when the owners property exist and it's not an empty array 
  car.owners.push("person1");
} else {
  // when the owners property does not exist or it's an empty array
  car.owners = [];
  car.owners.push("person2");
}
console.log(car)

// o/p { colour: 'white',type: 'electric',owners: [ 'person2' ] }
```

Comment: It's too much smart sample code rather than other sample code. It follows the ES6 version

Comment: what if `status` was assigned to `false` initially in the object? wouldn't `if(car.status){
  car.status = "sold";
}` not execute?

Comment: If the status is false or undefined it is not executed and output should be { colour: 'white', type: 'electric' }. My answer is most sophisticated than other answers. So, please accept my answer